# Running SoapUI and HermesJMS on headless Linux Server

Tags: linux, soapui, automated-tests

I'm trying to get SoapUI and HermesJMS to work with each other on a headless Linux server. And by "headless" I do mean headless; the only account we are authorized to use that has any kind of admin privileges is unable to forward an X-server session.

First, the steps I've done so far:

1. Unpacked the tar.gz containing SoapUI 4.6.0 into a soapui directory.
2. Using my own account, which has X-server, I ran the HermesJMS installer.
3. Set 777 permissions so the admin user could work with the files.
4. I entered the soapui-config.xml and test.xml files and told them where to find the hermes-config.xml

Independently, they both work. I can run a generic SoapUI test and if I use my X-server to run Hermes, I can see the queues I need to be using.

However, when I try to use the testrunner.sh, I get a NullPointer exception on HermesUtils.addHermesJarsToClasspath.

```
An error occured [java.lang.NullPointerException], see error log for details java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.jms.util.HermesUtils.addHermesJarsToClasspath(HermesUtils.java:120)
```

Any ideas on what the issue is? I tried running soapui's GUI the same way I ran Hermes' but I run into a segmentation fault on startup.

Comment: What is in the error logs?

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514808/combining-maven-soapui-and-hermesjms

Comment: The error logs aren't very useful, they just show the entire stack trace, but the same info (NullPointerException). I saw that question awhile back, but I'm not using Maven to do anything.

Comment: The error in that question seems similar to what you get. Can you try and see if some of the steps in the solutions there may apply to you? As a side note As on 23 Jan 2012 10:02 `JMS is the only thing that the soapUI Runner doesn't support. We will look into this in the future.` Could that be the problem. I got this statement from http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=11911
`